# ExtJs 4 Line chart performance

Tags: performance, extjs, charts, extjs4

I have a simple line chart in EXTJS4 with multiple series. The total count of points in lines is about ~5k.

ExtJs 4 chart renders it, but pretty slowly so I'm looking for a way to decrease rendering time. 
Y axis - numeric, X axis - time. 
Flash chart from ExtJs3 renders the same data set much faster.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider less resolution, your screen doesn't have 5000 pixels, that should help performance. I use http://code.google.com/p/flot/ when Ext charts are slow

Answer (score 2):

I recommend trying Flot for the charts instead: http://code.google.com/p/flot/